# Get SVG from canvas element and save it

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, save

Currently I'm creating a small application for a friend, who´s starting his PhD and needs to build some network graphs. So far everything works fine using the a Force Directed graph. The graphs nodes can be moved to style the layout.

[image]

The thing I can't get my head around is:

> **»how to extract the data from the canvas and save it to a SVG file«**.

#### What I tried:

I already tried accessing the image Data from the console with

```
var app.canvas = document.getElementById( 'graph-canvas' )
    .getContext( '2d' )
        .getImageData( 0, 0, 200, 200 );
```

and got an `(object) ImageData` in return. Now I can access the ↑ shown canvas data with `app.canvas.data`. (When I try too look up the values, the browser starts hanging and asks if the script should be stopped - Chrome & FF latest).

How would I go from here to get the SVG drawn and then saved by the click of a button?

**EDIT:**

So far I found out how to draw the SVG and add an `image/png` element to it. How ever, it´s not displaying.

```
// Add the test SVG el:
var svg = document.createElementNS( "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg" );
svg.setAttribute( 'style', 'border: 1px solid black;' )
        .setAttribute( 'width', '600' )
        .setAttribute( 'height', '400' )
        .setAttributeNS(
            'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/',
            'xmlns:xlink',
            'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
        );

// Call
importCanvas( document.getElementById( 'infovis-canvas' ), svg ); 

// Function: Add data to SVG
function importCanvas( sourceCanvas, targetSVG ) 
{
    // get base64 encoded png data url from Canvas
    var img_dataurl = sourceCanvas.toDataURL( "image/png" );

    var svg_img = document.createElementNS(
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        "image"
    );

    svg_img.setAttributeNS(
        'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink',
        'xlink:href',
        img_dataurl
    );
    jQuery( targetSVG.appendChild( svg_img ) )
        .appendTo( '#graph-container' );

    console.log( 'done' ); // Log & confirm
}
```

And finally the...

```
// ...resulting SVG element containing the image element
<svg style="border: 1px solid black;" width="600" height="400" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><image href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABQAAA(...)
```

---

*The UI works with jQuery UI, jQuery and the [The Jit/InfoVIZ](http://thejit.org/static/v20/Docs/files/Core/Core-js.html) library, so those are available.*

Comment: might help http://svgopen.org/2010/papers/62-From_SVG_to_Canvas_and_Back/

Comment: @mightyuhu Thanks - will give it a read. So far I have access to the data (see update).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export KinteticJS drawing to SVG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178146/export-kinteticjs-drawing-to-svg)

Comment: @Phrogz No. It's about exporting from canvas _bitmap_ to SVG. KineticJS is _vector_, which is dead simple to export. As simple as exporing to PNG from ↑.

Comment: @kaiser Thanks for clarifying; so the question was really "How to display a bitmap in SVG" and "How do I create an image from a Canvas".

Comment: @Phrogz N/P. Close: The Q is »How create an SVG vector image from a bitmap canvas element?« - Point is that I thought - when asking initially - that every canvas will _only_ hold SVG Data. My failure :/

Answer (score 17):

If you want to preserve it as a vector graphic instead of as a raster, you can try one of the libraries that translate the canvas API operations to svg.

**For [SVGKit](http://svgkit.sourceforge.net/SVGCanvas.html):**

```
var svgkitContext = new SVGCanvas(150,150);

function draw(ctx) {
   // ... normal canvas drawing commands go here ...
}

// draw to SVGKit canvas (svg) instead of canvasElement.getContext("2d")
draw(svgkitContext);
```

Full running [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/libraries/svgkit/example/canvas-to-svg.html) of the above.

**For [canvas-svg](http://code.google.com/p/canvas-svg/):**

```
var canvasSVGContext = new CanvasSVG.Deferred();
canvasSVGContext.wrapCanvas(document.querySelector("canvas"));
var canvasContext = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

function draw(ctx) {
    // ... normal canvas drawing commands go here ...
}

// draw to html5 canvas and record as svg at the same time
draw(canvasContext);

// append the svg result
var svg = document.appendChild(canvasContext.getSVG());
```

Full running [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/libraries/canvas-svg/canvas-to-svg.html) of the above.

**For generating svg instead:**

Another option is of course to make the graph as an svg in the first place, [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) is a javascript library that makes it easy to do this, see e.g [this example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/force.html) of a force directed graph.

Comment: Could you maybe extend your answer with a short example of how to throw the data into the canvas object using the first lib? Both look more like drawing libs to me and I couldn't find any tutorial or guid on how to draw the SVG from canvas `imageData`.

Comment: Erik, when I remove the links from your answer, your answer isn´t  helpful a single bit. Would you mind editing it one day and fixing it? So far the question has attracted 5k readers and you might have a solution...

Comment: I think your question is a little unclear. Do you want to simply draw a bitmap (read: this is what ImageData in canvas is) in an svg? Or do you want to generate true vector graphics from the commands used to produce the canvas? In the latter case the way to do it is to record the commands using a custom context object instead of the normal context returned from the canvas element itself.

Comment: Hi Erik is this answer considered state-of-the-art today? Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/force.html is 404!

Answer (score 8):

If you're limited to `ImageData` you're out of luck, because that's just a mere pixel array (see [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/ImageData)). You can't obtain a meaningful SVG image from there. You can probably pull off a `.png` representation...but that's a static image with no interaction.

If you're going to do some sort of canvas to SVG export, it's important how you're doing the canvas drawing. The best approach would be to use a library that maintains a canvas [scene graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph).

[Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) seems to be a good choice. You can do the drawing with canvas and then call `canvas.toSVG()` and get your svg image.

Comment: It seems you're right. I guess, I'll need to switch away from InfoVis to something that's pixel shuffeling, but drawing real vectors...

Comment: A drawback of fabric.js is that you then need to use the methods in that library for drawing to the canvas, so you'll need to change your existing code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently investigating other libraries that can draw Force Directed Graphs (not too many out there). Fabric.js is more a canvas-plain.js and not on the list.