# How can I save a processing.js canvas as vector

Tags: canvas, processing

Is there a way to save a canvas generated by processing.js as any kind of vector format, ideally in the browser? .toDataURL() returns raster, so it doesn't solve my problem.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273516) but it just points to two libraries without any further detail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't come across any SVG export for Processing.js. There are libraries for Processing that let you do that for sure however, they are Java specific. In fact, I don't think Processing.js uses SVG at all.

The [save](http://processingjs.org/reference/save_/) function lets you export the canvas as an raster, but not a vector image.

You might want to consider using other libraries that provide an SVG render context. Something like `Raphael.js` or `Two.js`.