# How to save canvas as vector image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I'm working on application for designing t-shirts on using `fabricjs` javascript library. T-shirt template(png) is positioned absolute to canvas. So when the canvas is rasterized to `SVG`, objects on canvas get saved.

I'm currently storing `SVG` data on database for displaying purpose. When the process of designing t-shirt is completed, it needs to be saved as vector image so that while zooming, it persists it's original quality. How this can be done?

Or how the system like [this](http://teespring.com/) saves high quality images?

Comment: Hi - what research have you done into this topic? did you google search? why were the results unsatisfactory?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273516/get-svg-from-canvas-element-and-save-it

Comment: You may be mixing up something here. An SVG is a vector image, therefore usually an SVG gets rasterized onto a canvas, not the other way round. If you have the SVG, you should already have the vector image that you are looking for.

Comment: @K3N, (nice link) but this isn't a duplicate question. The OP is using the FabricJS library which has a very nice .toSVG method which converts all the FabricJS objects into their SVG equivalents.

Comment: @markE did you bother to look at the *[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10283774/1693593)* in that post?

Comment: @markE you deleted your previous comment just to write that?

Comment: @markE it can be (and probably is) whatever you want it to be. Is this constructive? Why are we even having this discussion?

Answer (score 4):

FabricJS's `canvas.toSVG` is a very nice feature that takes the drawing commands that created your canvas content and converts them into a fully formed svg element.

For example, this code creates green rectangle on the canvas and then uses `canvas.toSVG` to convert it into a fully formed svg element.

```
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  height: 20,
  width: 20,
  fill: 'green'
}));
console.log(canvas.toSVG());
```

This is what the resulting svg element looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="800" height="700" xml:space="preserve"><desc>Created with Fabric.js 0.9.21</desc><rect x="-10" y="-10" rx="0" ry="0" width="20" height="20" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; fill: green; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(50 50)" /></svg>    </body>
```

As an SVG element, it can be scaled by the client with little loss of clarity.

Since FabricJS gives you a fully formed svg element, all you have to do is tell your server to include that svg element in the DOM of the webpage being served to the client.

It's literally as simple as this (this SVG rectangle scales with little loss of clarity).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- This is the exact SVG produced by canvas.toSVG and which was saved in your DB -->
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="800" height="700" xml:space="preserve"><desc>Created with Fabric.js 0.9.21</desc><rect x="-10" y="-10" rx="0" ry="0" width="20" height="20" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; fill: green; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(50 50)" /></svg>    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I generated svg data using `canvas.toSVG` method and saved it as `.svg` format. When I opened this file on illustrator it shows only text objects but not images. I opened svg file and found that `image xlink:href` is set to image link on AWS. What I want is to make a feature for downloading svg image by client and resize it to the desired size.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I can only suggest you create an image object with the AWS image as its source and reference that local image instead of directly referencing the AWS image.

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ifaqyhins6zrf47/art.svg?dl=0) what my svg image looks like. Now what I thinking to do is convert and resize svg to png using imagemagick. Or is there any good technique? What I want is png image of this svg of high resolution ~ 2000x2377