# Download svg file from storage.googleapis with webview - android

Tags: java, android, svg, webview, google-api

I would like to show some svg logos in my android mobile app. Some weeks ago google released AI www.autodraw.com (Web based tool for drawing)
I loaded the url in a webview, and everything works fine.

I would like to download the svg files (small pictures on top, the results of your drawings) directly to my app from the webview, when the user clicks one the choosed one. (after it, I would like to convert it to VectorDrawable and set it as a background of ImageViews to use it flexible with all pixel densities).

- Google allows you to download your drawings, but it returns a png file and not always centered (users will not draw correctly always). That's why I would like to download the svg directly.
  As an example of a result svg file from storage.googleapis:
  https://storage.googleapis.com/artlab-public.appspot.com/stencils/selman/house-01.svg

This is what I have now:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto_draw);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.autodraw_webview);
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.autodraw.com");

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Question:

Is it possible to get the svg file from the WebView to the app by user clicking one of the result images of his/her drawing ?

Comment: Hey Adrian, 

That is not SVG, it is Canvas. I don't think you can access these svg elements without a library that converts the canvas data. 

More details in this post; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273516/get-svg-from-canvas-element-and-save-it

Comment: You are true, because you are meaning the picture when you add it to canvas, but I just found the result image in chrome dev. tools and there is a link for the svg file from the storage.googleapis.
See the example on top.